# Keeping console window open when debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging, console-application

When I start a program without debugging (Ctrl+F5), I have to press a key to close the console window when the program is finished. When I start the program *with* debugging (F5), the console window closes immediately. Is there an option in Visual Studio that will keep the window open when debugging?

(I know of a thousand ways to do it "manually" in code, but I don't want to touch the code.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a break point to the ending bracket of the `main()` method. That way if the program finishes (unless it crashes in the process - which will trigger a break anyway) it will break no matter which return statement in the `main` was used.

Comment: this is not the correct way if you wanting to stop a console at the end use a readLn() break points are for debugging certain parts of your code.

Comment: @Barkermn01: That does violate the "don't want to touch the code" requirement. The breakpoint doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but you could do it manually

- add break point in the end of main method
- add the read function at the end of the main function so it will stay open to read the input and closed if you hit any key

Answer (score 0):

yea there is if you open your properties for the current project not solution,

And set it to console application from windows forms appliction and it will open for you and will only close when the application closes, or will close the application if you close the console.

and if you writing a console application just put a readLn(); at the end of the main() not a break point as that will stop your application from responding

Comment: **(I know of a thousand ways to do it "manually" in code, but I don't want to touch the code.)**

Comment: I said the way you can do it but if you a console application you should not use a break point to just leave the form do not learn to program badly there is nothing worse for another programmer than taking code of some one who has not got a clue what there doing if your going to learn how to do some thing learn to do it properly or dont bother! And, a break point will not work if the application is run standalone as in not in the Visual Studios Debugger!