# Why does my program immediately terminate after execution

Tags: c++

so I'm using MVS and I wrote this following program

```
// istream::ignore example
#include <iostream>     

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    char first, middle, last;

    std::cout << "Please, enter your first name and your surname: ";

    first = cin.get();           // get one character
    cin.ignore(256, ' ');        // ignore until space

    middle = cin.get();          //get one character
    cin.ignore(256, ' ');        //ignore until space

    last = std::cin.get();       // get one character

    std::cout << "Your initials are " << first << middle << last << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The program runs as it should, but as soon as it executes it immediately shuts down. Could somebody please explain what is making the program do this, and how I could fix it?

Comment: Do you mean it ends before you provided input ? Can you describe how you run it ? And what input you provide (if any) ?

Comment: Is "MVS" an acronym for Visual Studio, or something else?

Comment: as soon as I provide input the program displays the correct results then immediately terminates.

Comment: MVS means microsoft visual studio

Comment: This is normal. When a program ends the OS does not keep it around. If you hit ctrl-f5 the visual studio GUI will prompt you to close the window. Or put a breakpoint on the last statement. Or run it from a cmd.exe window. I expect there are 1000s of duplicates for this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066057/keeping-console-window-open-when-debugging

Comment: guys, there's a `cin.get();` at last; It **should** stop for user input. That's why it is there...

Comment: Your question is oddly worded.  As soon as it executes it should shut down.  Do you mean "it shuts down without waiting for a key press from the user"?

Answer (score 0):

The last cin.get() is eating new line character from `last = std::cin.get();` and automatically gets passed on.

Add `cin.ignore(256, '\n');` after `last = std::cin.get();` line

Or use a dummy `cin.get();`:

```
cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
```

Comment: For anything but toy examples this suggestion doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Why?? can you explain? @BenjaminBannier

Comment: Because the program doesn't terminate after it is done doing its thing. I'm pretty sure users would  see that as a bug.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier That's not the problem here, The OP wants to do that.. for his own reason. That's why he is using a dummy  `cin.get()` at last. And I am pretty much sure that he is doing this just for test purpose. and omit those dummy cin.get() at final process. But whether he is doing it for test or whatever that's not the problem. The problem is, he wants to do that.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier please think before useless comments or downvotes. If you have to say anything about the approach OP is going to or willing to take, put comments/downvotes on the original question not one of it's answer, and please provide legal reasoning too.

Comment: Even though there's no need for "legal reasoning" here, I'll give you mine: you propose to work around tool deficiencies *in the source itself* when the problem can be solved perfectly well inside the tool instead, see the linked duplicate. "Closing windows" has nothing to do with the program being written (e.g. my terminal window does not close when I exit an application), but is only due to the tool used to run that program.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier What if you want to promt this: `cout<<"Hit Enter to exit";`, There's pretty much area where this kind of prompt at end of the program is useful and user friendly.