# C# code not building/running even though i have no errors

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

so as the title says my C# code is not running/debugging even though i have 0 errors being shown.

I begin the debugging and all that happens is the console screen flashes quickly then exits with 0 errors. Even the .exe in the bin\debug folder does the exact same. All i'm receiving is a wall of text in the output section.

> Algorithms.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Algorithms.vshost.exe): Loaded `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll`. Symbols loaded.
>
> The thread `0x12b8` has exited with code `0 (0x0)`.
>
> The thread `0x289c` has exited with code `0 (0x0)`.
>
> The program `[15012] Algorithms.vshost.exe` has exited with code `0 (0x0)`.

I hope this is understandable enough! I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Code as requested by some! I hope it's helpful! I appreciate all the answers and help so far!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AlgorithmsResit
{
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    { }


    public static void AlgorithmSortInt(int[] array)
    {
        int j = array.Length - 1;
        int x, i, temp;

        for (x = 1; x <= j; ++x)
        {
            temp = array[x];
            for (i = x - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                if (temp < array[i]) array[i + 1] = array[i];
                else break;
            }
            array[1 + 1] = temp;
        }

    }

    public static void AlgorithmSortDouble(double[] array)
    {
        int j = array.Length - 1;
        int x, i;
        double temp;

        for (x = 1; x <= j; ++x)
        {
            temp = array[x];
            for (i = x - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                if (temp < array[i]) array[i + 1] = array[i];
                else break;
            }
            array[i + 1] = temp;
        }

    }
    public static void AlgorithmDateTime(DateTime[] array)
    {
        int j = array.Length - 1;
        int x, i;
        DateTime temp;

        for (x = 1; x <= j; ++x)
        {
            temp = array[x];
            for (i = x - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                if (temp < array[i]) array[i + 1] = array[i];
                else break;
            }
            array[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static void StringToSort(string[] array)
    {
        int x = array.Length - 1;

        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            for (int i = x; i > j; i--)
            {
                if (((IComparable)array[i - 1]).CompareTo(array[i]) > 0)
                {
                    var temp = array[i - 1];
                    array[i - 1] = array[i];
                    array[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    static void main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] Day1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFiles/Day_1.txt");
        List<int> Day1List = new List<int>();
        foreach (string Day in Day1)
        {
            int Days = Convert.ToInt32(Day);
            Day1List.Add(Days);
        }
        int[] Day1Arr = Day1List.ToArray();


        string[] Depth1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFiles/Depth_1.txt");
        List<double> Depth1List = new List<double>();
        foreach (string Depth in Depth1)
        {
            double Depths = Convert.ToDouble(Depth);
            Depth1List.Add(Depths);
        }
        double[] Depth1Arr = Depth1List.ToArray();


        string[] IRISID1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFiles/IRIS_ID_1.txt");
        List<int> Iris1List = new List<int>();
        foreach (string IRIS in IRISID1)
        {
            int Iris = Convert.ToInt32(IRIS);
            Iris1List.Add(Iris);
        }
        int[] Iris1Arr = Iris1List.ToArray();


        string[] Latitude1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFiles/Latitude_1.txt");
        List<double> Latitude1List = new List<double>();
        foreach (string Lat in Latitude1)
        {
            double Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(Latitude1);
            Latitude1List.Add(Latitude);
        }
        double[] Latitude1Arr = Latitude1List.ToArray();


        string[] Longitude1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFiles/Longitude_1.txt");
        List<double> Longitude1List = new List<double>();
        foreach (string Longitude in Longitude1)
        {
            double Longitudes = Convert.ToDouble(Longitude1);
            Longitude1List.Add(Longitudes);
        }
        double[] Longitude1Arr = Longitude1List.ToArray();


        string[] Magnitude1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFiles/Magnitude_1.txt");
        List<Double> Magnitude1List = new List<Double>();
        foreach (string Magnitude in Magnitude1)
        {
            double Magnitudes = Convert.ToDouble(Magnitude1);
            Magnitude1List.Add(Magnitudes);
        }
        double[] Magnitude1Arr = Magnitude1List.ToArray();

        string[] Month1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFiles/Month_1.txt");

        string[] Region1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFiles/Region_1.txt");


        string[] Time1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFiles/Time_1.txt");
        List<DateTime> Time1List = new List<DateTime>();
        foreach (string Time in Time1)
        {
            DateTime Times = Convert.ToDateTime(Time);
            Time1List.Add(Times);
        }
        DateTime[] Time1Arr = Time1List.ToArray();

        string[] Timestamp1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFiles/Timestamp_1.txt");
        List<int> Timestamp1List = new List<int>();
        foreach (string Timestamp in Timestamp1)
        {
            int Timestamps = Convert.ToInt32(Timestamp);
            Timestamp1List.Add(Timestamps);
        }
        int[] Timestamp1Arr = Timestamp1List.ToArray();


        string[] Year1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"TextFiles/Year_1.txt");
        List<int> Year1List = new List<int>();
        foreach (String Date in Year1)
        {
            int Dates = Convert.ToInt32(Date);
            Year1List.Add(Dates);
        }
        int[] Year1Arr = Year1List.ToArray();

        string UserArrayChoice, AscOrDescChoice;
        int ArrayChoice;

        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            count++;
            Console.Write("{0} ", Day1Arr[count]);
            Console.Write("{0} ", Depth1[count]);
            Console.Write("{0} ", IRISID1[count]);
            Console.Write("{0} ", Latitude1Arr[count]);
            Console.Write("{0} ", Longitude1Arr[count]);
            Console.Write("{0} ", Magnitude1Arr[count]);
            Console.Write("{0} ", Month1[count]);
            Console.Write("{0} ", Region1[count]);
            Console.Write("{0} ", Time1Arr[count]);
            Console.Write("{0} ", Timestamp1Arr[count]);
            Console.Write("{0}", Year1Arr[count]);
            Console.Write("\n");
        } while (count < Year1Arr.Length - 1);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of the file you would like to sort... \n1 ) Day_1.txt\n2 ) Depth_1.txt\n3 ) IRIS_ID_.txt\n4 ) Latitude_1.txt\n5 ) Longitude_1.txt\n6 ) Magnitude_1.txt\n7 ) Month_1.txt\n8 ) Region_1.txt\n9 ) Time_1.txt\n10 ) Timestamp_1.txt\n11 ) Year_1.txt\n12");
        UserArrayChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        ArrayChoice = Convert.ToInt32(UserArrayChoice);

        switch (UserArrayChoice)
        {
            case "1":
                UserArrayChoice = "Day_1.txt";
                break;
            case "2":
                UserArrayChoice = "Depth_1.txt";
                break;
            case "3":
                UserArrayChoice = "IRIS_ID_1.txt";
                break;
            case "4":
                UserArrayChoice = "Latitude_1.txt";
                break;
            case "5":
                UserArrayChoice = "Longitude_1.txt";
                break;
            case "6":
                UserArrayChoice = "Magnitude_1.txt";
                break;
            case "7":
                UserArrayChoice = "Month_1.txt";
                break;
            case "8":
                UserArrayChoice = "Region_1.txt";
                break;
            case "9":
                UserArrayChoice = "Time_1.txt";
                break;
            case "10":
                UserArrayChoice = "Timestamp_1.txt";
                break;
            case "11":
                UserArrayChoice = "Year_1.txt";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Has been selected, would you like to sort by Ascending or Descending?  ", UserArrayChoice);
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        AscOrDescChoice = Console.ReadLine();

        if (AscOrDescChoice == "Ascending" | AscOrDescChoice == "ascending")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Will sort in Ascending order!", UserArrayChoice);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
            switch (ArrayChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                    AlgorithmSortInt(Day1Arr);
                    foreach (int temp in Day1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} ", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    AlgorithmSortDouble(Depth1Arr);
                    foreach (double temp in Depth1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    AlgorithmSortInt(Iris1Arr);
                    foreach (int temp in Iris1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    AlgorithmSortDouble(Latitude1Arr);
                    foreach (double temp in Latitude1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:
                    AlgorithmSortDouble(Longitude1Arr);
                    foreach (double temp in Longitude1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 6:
                    AlgorithmSortDouble(Magnitude1Arr);
                    foreach (double temp in Magnitude1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 7:
                    StringToSort(Month1);
                    foreach (string temp in Month1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 8:
                    StringToSort(Region1);
                    foreach (string temp in Region1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 9:
                    AlgorithmDateTime(Time1Arr);
                    foreach (DateTime temp in Time1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 10:
                    AlgorithmSortInt(Timestamp1Arr);
                    foreach (int temp in Timestamp1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 11:
                    AlgorithmSortInt(Year1Arr);
                    foreach (int temp in Year1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }

        else if (AscOrDescChoice == "Descending" | AscOrDescChoice == "descending")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Will sort in Descending order!", UserArrayChoice);
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

            switch (ArrayChoice)

            {
                case 1:
                    AlgorithmSortInt(Day1Arr);
                    Array.Reverse(Day1Arr);
                    foreach (int temp in Day1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} ", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    AlgorithmSortDouble(Depth1Arr);
                    Array.Reverse(Depth1Arr);
                    foreach (double temp in Depth1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    AlgorithmSortInt(Iris1Arr);
                    Array.Reverse(Iris1Arr);
                    foreach (int temp in Iris1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    AlgorithmSortDouble(Latitude1Arr);
                    Array.Reverse(Latitude1Arr);
                    foreach (double temp in Latitude1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:
                    AlgorithmSortDouble(Longitude1Arr);
                    Array.Reverse(Longitude1Arr);
                    foreach (double temp in Longitude1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 6:
                    AlgorithmSortDouble(Magnitude1Arr);
                    Array.Reverse(Magnitude1Arr);
                    foreach (double temp in Magnitude1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 7:
                    StringToSort(Month1);
                    Array.Reverse(Month1);
                    foreach (string temp in Month1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 8:
                    StringToSort(Region1);
                    Array.Reverse(Region1);
                    foreach (string temp in Region1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 9:
                    AlgorithmDateTime(Time1Arr);
                    Array.Reverse(Time1Arr);
                    foreach (DateTime temp in Time1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 10:
                    AlgorithmSortInt(Timestamp1Arr);
                    Array.Reverse(Timestamp1Arr);
                    foreach (int temp in Timestamp1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

                case 11:
                    AlgorithmSortInt(Year1Arr);
                    Array.Reverse(Year1Arr);
                    foreach (int temp in Year1Arr)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", temp);
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Response!");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of the file you would like to search... \n1 ) Day_1.txt\n2 ) Depth_1.txt\n3 ) IRIS_ID_1\n4 ) Latitude_1\n5 ) Longitude_1\n6 ) Magnitude_1\n7 ) Month_1\n8 ) Region_1\n9 ) Time_1\n10 ) Timestamp_1\n11 ) Year_1\n12");
        UserArrayChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        ArrayChoice = Convert.ToInt32(UserArrayChoice);

        switch (UserArrayChoice)
        {
            case "1":
                UserArrayChoice = "Day_1.txt";
                break;

            case "2":
                UserArrayChoice = "Depth_1.txt";
                break;

            case "3":
                UserArrayChoice = "IRIS_ID_1.txt";
                break;

            case "4":
                UserArrayChoice = "Latitude_1.txt";
                break;

            case "5":
                UserArrayChoice = "Longitude_1.txt";
                break;

            case "6":
                UserArrayChoice = "Magnitude_1.txt";
                break;

            case "7":
                UserArrayChoice = "Month_1.txt";
                break;

            case "8":
                UserArrayChoice = "Region_1.txt";
                break;

            case "9":
                UserArrayChoice = "Time_1.txt";
                break;

            case "10":
                UserArrayChoice = "Timestamp_1.txt";
                break;

            case "11":
                UserArrayChoice = "Year_1.txt";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has been selected! Please enter what you would like to search - ", UserArrayChoice);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
        string SearchTemp = Console.ReadLine();
        bool Found = false;
        int counter = 0;

        switch (ArrayChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                int SearchDay = Convert.ToInt32(SearchTemp);
                for (int x = 0; x < Day1Arr.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (SearchDay == Day1Arr[x])
                    {
                        Found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (Found == true) { Console.WriteLine("Successful! :-)"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful! Sorry :-("); }
                break;

            case 2:
                double DepthSearch = Convert.ToDouble(SearchTemp);
                for (int x = 0; x < Depth1Arr.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (DepthSearch == Depth1Arr[x])
                    {
                        Found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (Found == true) { Console.WriteLine("Successful!:-)"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful! Sorry :-("); }
                break;

            case 3:
                int SearchIris = Convert.ToInt32(SearchTemp);
                for (int x = 0; x < Iris1Arr.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (SearchIris == Iris1Arr[x])
                    {
                        Found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (Found == true) { Console.WriteLine("Successful! :-)"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful! Sorry :-("); }
                break;

            case 4:
                double SearchLatitude = Convert.ToDouble(SearchTemp);
                for (int x = 0; x < Latitude1Arr.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (SearchLatitude == Latitude1Arr[x])
                    {
                        Found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (Found == true) { Console.WriteLine("Successful! :-)"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful! Sorry :-("); }
                break;

            case 5:
                double SearchLong = Convert.ToDouble(SearchTemp);
                for (int x = 0; x < Longitude1Arr.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (SearchLong == Longitude1Arr[x])
                    {
                        Found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (Found == true) { Console.WriteLine("Successful! :-)"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful! Sorry :-("); }
                break;

            case 6:
                double SearchMag = Convert.ToDouble(SearchTemp);
                for (int x = 0; x < Magnitude1Arr.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (SearchMag == Magnitude1Arr[x])
                    {
                        Found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (Found == true) { Console.WriteLine("Successful! :-)"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful! Sorry :-("); }
                break;

            case 7:
                foreach (var Months in Month1)
                {
                    if (Months.Contains(SearchTemp))
                    {
                        count++;
                        Found = true;
                        Console.Write("{0} ", Day1Arr[counter]);
                        Console.Write("{0} ", Depth1Arr[counter]);
                        Console.Write("{0} ", Iris1Arr[counter]);
                        Console.Write("{0} ", Latitude1Arr[counter]);
                        Console.Write("{0} ", Longitude1Arr[counter]);
                        Console.Write("{0} ", Magnitude1Arr[counter]);
                        Console.Write("{0} ", Month1[counter]);
                        Console.Write("{0} ", Region1[counter]);
                        Console.Write("{0} ", Time1Arr[counter]);
                        Console.Write("{0} ", Timestamp1Arr[counter]);
                        Console.Write("{0} ", Year1Arr[counter]);
                        Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                }
                if (Found == true) { Console.WriteLine("Successful! :-)"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful! Sorry :-("); }
                break;

            case 8:
                foreach (var Regions in Region1)
                {
                    if (Regions.Contains(SearchTemp))
                    {
                        Found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (Found == true) { Console.WriteLine("Successful! :-)"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful! Sorry :-("); }
                break;

            case 9:
                DateTime SearchDate = Convert.ToDateTime(SearchTemp);
                for (int x = 0; x < Time1Arr.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (SearchDate == Time1Arr[x])
                    {
                        Found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (Found == true) { Console.WriteLine("Successful! :-)"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful! Sorry :-("); }
                break;

            case 10:
                int SearchTimestamp = Convert.ToInt32(SearchTemp);
                for (int x = 0; x < Timestamp1Arr.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (SearchTimestamp == Timestamp1Arr[x])
                    {
                        Found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (Found == true) { Console.WriteLine("Successful! :-)"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful! Sorry :-("); }
                break;

            case 11:
                int SearchYear = Convert.ToInt32(SearchTemp);
                for (int x = 0; x < Year1Arr.Length; x++)
                {
                    {
                        Found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (Found == true) { Console.WriteLine("Successful! :-)"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Unsuccessful! Sorry :-("); }
                break;
              
        }
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Show code. Your main thread probably finish to execute the code and close application.

Comment: Did you set breakpoints when you debugged?

Comment: What makes you say it's not building or running? That "wall of text in the output section" indicates that it *did* build and run (and exit with code 0).

Comment: regarding description, seems like it compiles and runs, but no functionality is added to console application. It starts and finishes and everything is okay. More information would be nice.

Comment: I uploaded my full code, is there any indication to what might be causing this to happen?

Comment: @Axios, It would be not the debugger tool issue, it would be related to your code, for example, if you just debug your app using F11(Step Into), it would just called the private static void Main(string[] args){}, it has no code in this Main function, and your code also has another main function like "static void main(string[] args)", you need to really view two main functions and edit them in your side.I think you could get the debugging information again after you edit the main functions correctly.

Comment: @Axios, What about this issue? Do you get any latest information about it?

Answer (score 1):

What I know that it is just debugging message. You can switch that off by right clicking into the output window and uncheck the thread ended message.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs4c1wda.aspx

(1)Please add a breakpoint in your app, and then debug it again.

Like this thread:
[Keeping console window open when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066057/keeping-console-window-open-when-debugging).

(2)If you run it with “start without debugging”, it would not be closed. You could also add Console.ReadLine()in your app like this thread.

(3)If you just debug your app and get this messages, please also enable the Exceptions settings under Debugger->Windows menu, and make sure that no Exception.